# Boundedness of scaled derivativefor bounded function with bounded scaled second derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I assume the following to be true but I am too dumb to show it. 
So let $u \in C_b \bigl( [0, \infty) \bigr)$ be a bounded continuous real-valued function such that $u \in C^2 \bigl( (0, \infty) \bigr)$ and $r \in (-1,1)$ a fixed number. Assume further that $t \mapsto t^{-r} \frac{d}{dt} t^r u'(t) \in C_b \bigl( [0, \infty) \bigr)$. Show that $t \mapsto t^r u'(t) \in C_b \bigl( [0, \infty) \bigr)$. I think I can do $r \in (-1,0]$ by considering the function $v(s) := u \left( s^{\frac{1}{1-r}} \right)$ and applying the mean value theorem and the fundamental theorem as one would do in the case $r=0$. Further this strategy shows in my opinion $t \mapsto t^r u'(t) \in C \bigl( [0, \infty) \bigr)$. I struggle with the boundedness for big values of $t$ and $r \in (0,1)$. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\dfrac{d\,t^ru'(t)}{dt}?$

Comment: To which part are you refering? So I assume and try to show that $t \mapsto t^r \frac{du}{dt}$ is bounded and one can use that $u$ itself is bounded but also $t \mapsto t^{-r} \frac{d t^{r}u'}{d t} = t \mapsto u''(t) + \frac{r}{t} u'(t)$. I hope that clarifies what confused you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems wrong. I am not 100 % sure but sure enough. Consider as a counter example 
$u(t) := \sin^{\alpha}(t^{\beta})$ for given $r \in (0,1)$ with $1 - r < \beta < 1$ and $\alpha > \frac{1+r}{1-r}$.